# Alert box counter doesn't increment

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cookies, session-cookies

So, I wanted to count how many times a user accesses my game and I wanted to show it up to the user with an alert box. The thing is that my counter increments only once, after that I can refresh the page how many times I want but the number won't increment. Here is my code:

```
var access = 0;
function checkCookie() {
access++;
var user=getCookie("username");
if (user != "") {
alert("Welcome " + user + "! You accessed the game " + access + " 
times" );
} else {
 user = prompt("Please enter your name:","");
 if (user != "" && user != null) {
   setCookie("username", user, 30);
 }
}
}
```

I will really appreciate if someone can help me out!

Comment: Well you would need to store `access` in a cookie too and update it each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the page is refreshed, this Javascript code will be refreshed and restarted from scratch. So the line `var access = 0` will be called every time the page is refreshed.

For that reason, when you are incrementing the variable `access`, you need to store it somewhere more permanent (e.g. a cookie), and whenever the page gets reloaded, get its value from there instead of using `var access = 0`

Answer (score 1):

From where checkCookie is being called? As per this code var access will initialize from 0 and inside  checkCookie() , it will add 1 in it. so it will always give you 1. You may want to store variable "access" somewhere in cookie etc. and read it from there and then add 1 in it.